# R loop over levels of a factor to create a sequence of numbers for each level

Tags: r, gps, split-apply-combine

I'm working on a dataframe with GPS data from beavers, the dataframe includes on column with the animals id (see `$id` below) which is a factor with 26 levels. For each beaver, we have several GPS values - the number differs from animal to animal.

I now want to create a separate column with "Time after capture" per individual in 15 min intervalls, starting at 0 min. For the 15 min intervall I tried to create a sequence

```
TimePostRel <- seq(from = 0, along = x, by = 15)
```

Now I'm not sure how to define x so it refers to each individual. Should I use the split function to split up the dataframe? We do have a date/time column too, but the problem is that we have no GPS points during daytime (when the animals are sleeping), resulting in breaks that we want to exclude from the `TimePostRel` calculations (we just want to refer to "active time" after capture).

This is the dataframe:

```
'data.frame':   6425 obs. of  22 variables:
 $ nb              : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ x               : num  517710 517680 NA 517625 517624 ...
 $ y               : num  6587730 6587759 NA 6587929 6588014 ...
 $ date            : POSIXct, format: "2010-04-10 05:15:00" "2010-04-10 05:30:00" "2010-04-10         05:45:00" "2010-04-10 06:00:00" ...
 $ dx              : num  -30.2 NA NA -0.4 -39.2 ...
 $ dy              : num  28.8 NA NA 85.7 126.8 ...
 $ dist            : num  41.7 NA NA 85.7 132.7 ...
 $ dt              : num  900 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 NA 900 ...
 $ R2n             : num  0 1743 NA 46880 88416 ...
 $ abs.angle       : num  2.38 NA NA 1.58 1.87 ...
 $ rel.angle       : num  NA NA NA NA 0.295 ...
 $ id              : Factor w/ 26 levels "Andreas","Apple",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ burst           : Factor w/ 329 levels "Andreas.1","Andreas.2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ sex             : int  2 2 NA 2 2 2 NA 2 2 2 ...
 $ season          : int  2 2 NA 2 2 2 NA 2 2 2 ...
 $ try             : int  33 34 NA 36 37 38 NA 39 40 41 ...
 $ x.sats          : int  5 5 NA 5 5 5 NA 6 5 6 ...
 $ hdop            : num  2.1 4.2 NA 2.7 3.3 2.1 NA 2.5 2.8 2.2 ...
 $ lodge.x         : num  517595 517595 NA 517595 517595 ...
 $ lodge.y         : num  6587806 6587806 NA 6587806 6587806 ...
 $ NSD_lodge       : num  19039 9440 NA 15909 44268 ...
 $ nsd_1stGPSpoint : num  0 1743 NA 46880 88416 ...
```

Somebody nows how to solve this? Thanks in advance!!

Cheers,
Patricia

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very quickly in `data.table`. I assume your data is called `dta`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dta)   ## change format
dta[, TimePostRel:=seq(from = 0, along = x, by = 15), by=x]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `plyr` package can also accomplish this task. For a data frame that has a column of factors, use the transform option of `ddply`:

```
library(plyr)
# create a data frame where column x is a factor
df <- data.frame(x=c(rep("b",6),rep("a",3),rep("c",4)))
# apply sequence to each level within x
df <- ddply(df,"x",transform,t=seq(from=0,by=15,length.out=length(x)))
```

Note that the rows of the new data frame are ordered to match the factor levels of column x:

```
print(df)
   x  t
1  a  0
2  a 15
3  a 30
4  a 45
5  a 60
6  a 75
7  b  0
8  b 15
9  b 30
10 c  0
11 c 15
12 c 30
13 c 45
```